# doctrine migrations phar, how to setup type mapping?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to use doctrine migrations in my non-symfony project, so I got the phar standalone from https://github.com/doctrine/migrations. I configured everything properly (db-configuration and configuration) and then when doing "migrations:status" I get the error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>   Unknown database type enum requested,
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.

Now there are many resources on how to fix this in the context of a symfony app (for instance http://wildlyinaccurate.com/doctrine-2-resolving-unknown-database-type-enum-requested) but where can I put this type mapping in this case? Should I extract the .phar, put the code in it (where?) and then re-package it? (how?)

Comment: You need to use migrations and setup the CLI on your own. Start from cloning https://github.com/doctrine/migrations and installing via composer. After that, customize your CLI runner to setup the connection according to your own needs.

Comment: In way which Ocramius suggests extra options wouldn't work (--db-config, --configuration). It's well known bug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What Ocramius said:

You need to use migrations and setup the CLI on your own. Start from cloning github.com/doctrine/migrations and installing via composer. After that, customize your CLI runner to setup the connection according to your own needs.

Comment: Provide the way, please

Answer (score 7):

I have tried something for Zend framework and it worked:

Open ./vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php
Search for function `initializeDoctrineTypeMappings()`
create an entry for enum as,

```
'enum' => 'string'
```

Worked like charm !

Answer (score 0):

That problem resolved in this fork
https://github.com/dyadyavasya/migrations

By default Doctrine does not map the MySQL enum type to a Doctrine type. This is because Enums contain state (their allowed values) and Doctrine types don’t.

Use fork at link and you can register MySQL ENUMs to map to Doctrine strings. 
This way Doctrine always resolves ENUMs to Doctrine strings.

migrations.yml

```
name: Doctrine Sandbox Migrations
migrations_namespace: DoctrineMigrations
table_name: doctrine_migration_versions
migrations_directory: /path/to/migrations/classes/DoctrineMigrations
mapping_types:
    enum: string
```

More information - https://github.com/dyadyavasya/migrations#migrationsyml

Comment: This answer as it is needs some work.  You say that the problem stated by the op is "resolved" at the link you provide, but you need to specify in which way it is resolved.  If you edit your answer to provide more information here about the link your giving and why it is relevant to the question, you may receive +1's from other readers.