# Doctrine- unknown database type enum requested

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using doctrine 2 within zend framework 2. To generate entities using database table, the console command used is:

```
php doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --force --from-database annotation ./export
```

When i run above command, it throws an error:

**Unknown database type enum requested**

How to solve this issue?

Comment: From the docs: "(...) By default Doctrine does not map the MySQL enum type to a Doctrine type. (...)". Check the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/mysql-enums.html), there are two solutions proposed.

Comment: I followed this link for answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086148/doctrine-migrations-phar-how-to-setup-type-mapping

Comment: Doctrine does not support MySQL ENUM by default as ENUM is specific to MySQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add:

```
'doctrine_type_mappings' => array(
    'enum' => 'string'
)
```

in your global configuration file located in `/config/autoload/global.php`.

Example code:

```
        return array(
            'doctrine' => array(
                'connection' => array(
                    'orm_default' => array(
                        'driverClass' =>'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                        'params' => array(
                            'host'     => 'localhost',
                            'port'     => '3306',
                            'user'     => 'username',
                            'password' => 'password',
                            'dbname'   => 'DevBrew',

                        ),
                        // To automatically convert enum to string
                        'doctrine_type_mappings' => array(
                            'enum' => 'string'
                        ),
                    )
                )
            )
       );
```